# Set timeout in Apache ACL

Tags: apache-2.4, access-control-list, timeout

for a page in an Apache webserver under ACL, is there a way to force apache to prompt again for credentials after a fixed timeout?
For example, user tries to access the url, he fills the credentials and displays the page.
After 10 minutes the webserver asks again for credentials and in case they're correct it responds with 401 page.
Best regards

Comment: It would be even good to make every page expire with timeout after a certain time. And then the user have to open another browser page and ask for the page

Comment: That depends on how authentication is managed. Generally your can expire sessions server-side, but when you're using [Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) that option doesn't exist and neither the client nor the server can force  a "log out" and re-validate credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AuthDigestNonceLifetime](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#authdigestnoncelifetime) directive to set when the password will expire. For this you will `need mod_auth_digest`.

From Apache site:

> The AuthDigestNonceLifetime directive controls how long the server
> nonce is valid. When the client contacts the server using an expired
> nonce the server will send back a 401 with stale=true. If seconds is
> greater than 0 then it specifies the amount of time for which the
> nonce is valid; this should probably never be set to less than 10
> seconds. If seconds is less than 0 then the nonce never expires.

Comment: Hi, I think it could work only if credentials are stored locally and not when using ldap. Is there a way instead to make all the pages require expire with timeout after a fixed time?

Comment: @solonely, you did not mention LDAP in question. And AFAIK expiration is connected to credentials, not pages.

Comment: Yes, you are true... I'm sorry, I did not explain correctly the point